# How to calculate Current quarter and last month of previous quarter in List View?

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I need a list view to display List of records of current quarter and last month of previous quarter. I think I need to write a formula field to calculate current quarter and last month of previous quarter records.

Can anyone suggest me with formula how to write for above condition or any other way to achieve the above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If January starts a quarter the following checkbox formula should be works :

```
OR(
    /* When the year is similar between the date field and current year */
    AND(
        YEAR(  DateField__c ) = YEAR( TODAY() ),
        OR(
            /* Check if is the date field is on the same quarter of today */
            CEILING( MONTH( DateField__c) / 3 ) = CEILING( MONTH( TODAY() ) / 3 ),
            /* Or if the date field + one month is on the same quarter of today */
            AND (CEILING( MONTH( ADDMONTHS(DateField__c,1) ) / 3 ) = CEILING( MONTH( TODAY() ) / 3 ), MONTH( DateField__c ) < 12)
        )
    ),
    /* And we manage the case of the december of previous year */
    AND(
        YEAR( DateField__c ) = YEAR( TODAY() )-1,
        MONTH( DateField__c) = 12,
        CEILING( MONTH( TODAY() ) / 3 ) = 1 
    )
)
```

In your list view add this checkbox formula in your filter with "true" value.

Comment: Hi David Thanks for your help. Actually begin of the first quarter is April as per our client. So is this formula will work if begin of the first quarter is April?

Comment: Yes the formula should answer to your need. The mandatory thing is not that January is the begin of the 1st quarter but January have to start a quarter. So in your case it's ok because your Q4 starts with January.

(I just edited the formula to avoid a problem so think to update your implementation.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer to solved when you have finished to test this formula.

Comment: @chris my solution solved your problem or not ?

Comment: Thank you David.